# How to detect whether user liked a FB Page on pageload?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a FB Page "DEF" that has a parent FB Page "ABC"  I want to place a like button on an FB Page Tab on DEF that allows users to like the parent FB Page.  Is there a way to detect whether the user has already liked ABC on page load?

My initial assessment is that I would have to require the user authorize my app on DEF and then do an API call to the user's likes to check IDs.

I would really like to avoid authorizing the app if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no... you can't. Although the Facebook Page's tab gives developers the advantage of knowing the current user whether liked "DEF" or not via "signed_request", but it will never tell you about "ABC".

unfortunately, to yield the best results, you will have to authorize the app with "user_likes" permission, followed by checking if he has liked "ABC".

Comment: Well one could redirect the user from a page tab on DEF to a page tab on ABC, check whether they liked ABC there, and then redirect them back to the tab on DEF … and keeping the info about liking ABC either in a common shared session, or pass it as `app_data` parameter when redirecting back from DEF to ABC … but that’s a rather hack-y workaround, and does not make for a nice user experience.

Comment: Agreed.  I really dislike this request.  Hopefully it will go away LOL